# Would it be legal for private citizens to send postcards on behalf of candidate for office in United States?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

As a private citizen without affiliation to any political entity, is it legally permissible for me to send postcards endorsing a candidate for office to addresses in the United States?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You as a private citizen (of the United States) may send postcards at your expense endorsing a candidate ([FEC](http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/electioneering.shtml)).  You may send an unlimited number.  You may have to post a disclaimer.  The relevant law is at  [11 CFR 110.11(a)](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2014-title11-vol1/xml/CFR-2014-title11-vol1-sec110-11.xml), e.g.

> A disclaimer required by paragraph (a) of this section must contain the following information:
>   (1) If the communication, including any solicitation, is paid for and authorized by a candidate, an authorized committee of a candidate, or an agent of either of the foregoing, the disclaimer must clearly state that the communication has been paid for by the authorized political committee;
>   (2) If the communication, including any solicitation, is authorized by a candidate, an authorized committee of a candidate, or an agent of either of the foregoing, but is paid for by any other person, the disclaimer must clearly state that the communication is paid for by such other person and is authorized by such candidate, authorized committee, or agent; or
>   (3) If the communication, including any solicitation, is not authorized by a candidate, authorized committee of a candidate, or an agent of either of the foregoing, the disclaimer must clearly state the full name and permanent street address, telephone number, or World Wide Web address of the person who paid for the communication, and that the communication is not authorized by any candidate or candidate's committee.
>   (c) Disclaimer specifications—(1) Specifications for all disclaimers. A disclaimer required by paragraph (a) of this section must be presented in a clear and conspicuous manner, to give the reader, observer, or listener adequate notice of the identity of the person or political committee that paid for and, where required, that authorized the communication. A disclaimer is not clear and conspicuous if it is difficult to read or hear, or if the placement is easily overlooked.
>   (2) Specific requirements for printed communications. In addition to the general requirement of paragraphs (b) and (c)(1) of this section, a disclaimer required by paragraph (a) of this section that appears on any printed public communication must comply with all of the following:
>   (i) The disclaimer must be of sufficient type size to be clearly readable by the recipient of the communication. A disclaimer in twelve (12)-point type size satisfies the size requirement of this paragraph (c)(2)(i) when it is used for signs, posters, flyers, newspapers, magazines, or other printed material that measure no more than twenty-four (24) inches by thirty-six (36) inches.
>   (ii) The disclaimer must be contained in a printed box set apart from the other contents of the communication.
>   (iii) The disclaimer must be printed with a reasonable degree of color contrast between the background and the printed statement. A disclaimer satisfies the color contrast requirement of this paragraph (c)(2)(iii) if it is printed in black text on a white background or if the degree of color contrast between the background and the text of the disclaimer is no less than the color contrast between the background and the largest text used in the communication.
>   (iv) The disclaimer need not appear on the front or cover page of the communication as long as it appears within the communication, except on communications, such as billboards, that contain only a front face.
>   (v) A communication that would require a disclaimer if distributed separately, that is included in a package of materials, must contain the required disclaimer.

There may be more restrictions if someone else gives you money to pay for printing, postage, or other expenses.  But if you are doing this at your own expense, send as many as you want.  There also might be issues if you were a foreign citizen.  But for a US citizen, this would be a rather straight forward first amendment, freedom of the press issue.

Comment: Actually, provide the text and source of a law *against*